# Dúvida com nível de acesso e login em PHP

Tags: php

Bom tenho uma dúvida e queria a opinião de pessoas mais experientes.

Tenho um sistema em PHP que usa Mysql. Tenho uma tabela chamada 'acesso' onde salvo as opções que o usuário tem para acessar o sistema. O problema e que toda vez que carrego a página tenho que fazer o 'select' no BD.

Quero melhorar a performance do sistema, e tenho tomado várias medidas para isso. E uma delas é tentar diminuir os 'select'.

Bom vamos a dúvida, o que eu quero saber é:
1- Essa e a melhor forma de fazer isso?
2- Seria mais fácil salvar as permissões do usuário na sessão, para evitar o select?
3- A leitura da sessão e mais rápida do que o select no BD?

Bom, aguardo a ajuda para uma boa solução.

Comment: Quais são as informações que vc busca no seleção? E com que frequência elas são alteradas?

Comment: Bom elas raramente são alteradas, pois elas são salvas quando o usuário e cadastrado. Bom ela e uma tabela que se chama 'acesso', e conta uns 40 campos. Exemplo: o campos 'editar_produto' nele eu salvo 's' ou 'n'. Com isso eu sei se o usuário pode editar os produtos.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, mas já vi que o @ItaloRodrigo fez uma boa resposta! +1 para você e para a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Essa e a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Não, pois cada vez que você acessa o banco de dados, perde tempo.

2- Seria mais fácil salvar as permissões do usuário na sessão, para evitar o select?

Sim, essa é a melhor solução na minha opinião (pode ser que existam outras), pois assim você não vai ter que consultar o banco cada vez que abre a página.

3- A leitura da sessão e mais rápida do que o select no BD?

Sim

Comment: eu uso certificado ssl, e possível que alguém altere os dados da sessão ou tenha acesso a eles?